# clear replaySubject buffer rxjava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

It seems like there should be a ReplaySubject.clear() method. Currently I'm assigning a new ReplaySubject.create() to my field whenever I want to clear my subject but it seems like overkill. Does anybody know if there is a clear method that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1794)

Comment: It is not supported because it requires harsher protocol (i.e., ensure that no active consumers get discontinued event streams). There is a way to achieve some of the effects via time-bound replaying where the scheduler is the TestScheduler. Whenever you want to "clear" the Subject, you move the virtual time ahead of the replay max age and new consumers will not see the old data. Note however that, currently, this won't free the internal data until a fresh onXXX method call happens.

Comment: thanks for the response @akarnokd. Would it be considered bad practice to simply set mySubject = ReplaySubject.create() whenever I want to clear the subject and start again? Bearing in mind that I only  ever have a single subscriber which is unsubscribed at that point. My use case is streaming audio chunks to a server, made complicated by the fact that i need to start recording chunks before the connection is made. Once made, i replay everyhting from the subject and continue serially pushing chunks through a connection until the user cancels .

Comment: In that specific case where you control both the creation and consumption it is reasonable to solve the problem that way.